# Relationship between indicativo presente and congiuntivo presente of 1st person plural (noi) conjugation?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conjunctions

I noticed that all Italian verbs has the same conjugation for indicative present and subjunctive present for subject *noi*. The form also seems to have a closer relationship with the subjunctive forms (e.g. *abbiamo* is closer to *abbia* rather than *ha*, so is *siamo* to *sia*). I can't even find a single exception (is that right?). What is the story behind this "incidence"?

Comment: There is indeed a story (albeit a fairly simple one), but I'll be busy in the next couple of days. Hopefully someone will answer before me, if not I'll try to remember this question by then.

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks Denis! Mind taking a look at my own answer?

Comment: Sorry, my free time took a turn for the worst this Monday. Glad you found a good answer anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *A Linguistic History of Italian* by Mardin Maiden,

> The reasons for the spread of the inflection *-iamo* are obscure, although it clearly originates in the Latin second and fourth conjugation subjunctives in *-eamus* and *-iamus*.

Following the text, here are the observations:

The Latin active present subjunctive appears to be the origin of all these modern *-iamo*. The ending *-iamo* (together with 2nd-plural *-iate*) was originally restricted to a small set of frequently used verbs, such as *HABEAMUS* > **a'bjamo* > *abbiamo* and *SAPIAMUS* > **sa'pjamo* > *sappiamo*.

Based on those verbs, the endings *-iamo* and *-iate* later found their way to the replacement of the subjunctive of all conjugations, replacing their "original" forms (e.g. *cantiamo* = *cant-* + *-iamo*, instead of **cantemo* < Latin *CANTEMUS*). By mid-13th century, the replacement had already finished. The ending *-iamo* also had a consistent appearance in indicatives of the first conjugation (e.g. *portiamo*), but still within a limited range (e.g. both *vendemo* and *vendiamo* were found, but only *dormimo*, no *dormiamo*). (Wanner, 1975)

Having established a bridgehead in the first conjugation, the ending *-iamo* then spread to the first person plural indicative of remaining conjugations. Following the prevalence of *-iamo* in indicative, one of the basic words **semo* (< Latin *SUMUS*) also got replaced by *siamo*, favoring the ultimate generalization in *--iamo* endings in all verbs.

However, as stated by Martin, it's still unknown why the 2nd person plural indicative didn't get replaced by the subjunctive along with the move (e.g. we have indicative *voi cantate* but subjunctive *che voi cantiate*).

Comment: Excellent answer! I would only add that, like in the case of many other strange changes, the original forms survived in many (most?) regional languages (parlamo, vedemo, finimo...)