# Why are the 2nd/3rd singular forms of present of « potere » irregular?

Tags: verbs, etymology

The verb *potere* comes from Latin *posse* and the conjugation table follows regular Latin → Italian patterns except for *puoi* and *può*. Why is that?

```
Latin     Italian
possum    posso
potes     puoi
potest    può
possimus* possiamo
potestis  potete
possunt   possono
```

Why doesn't Italian speak *tu *poti* and *lui *pote*?

<sup>* Latin *possimus* is given as the origin of *possiamo* instead of *possumus* because all 1st-person plural indicative present forms of Italian verbs [are back-ported](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10169/4814) from the subjunctive present forms.</sup>

Comment: Wasn't it _possumus_? In general, it is _pot-_ + forms of _sum_ verb.

Comment: @DaG Specifically regarding the fact that all Italian *noi* forms of indicative present are backported from subjunctive present.

Comment: Not sure I understand: you have deliberately given the subjunctive rather than the indicative form for the 4th person for that reason? If so, perhaps you could make a note about it.

Comment: @DaG That's right. I added a note about that

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The forms *puoti* and *puote* (obtained from *poti* and *pote* by regular stressed open syllable diphtongization) are in fact attested in the early Tuscan and survived in literary Italian till quite late (in fact, arguably till today, even). See for example the [famous verse](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuolsi_cos%C3%AC_col%C3%A0_dove_si_puote), from Dante's *Comedy*

> Vuolsi così colà dove si **puote**
>   ciò che si vuole, e più non dimandare

("So it is wanted where one is able to do what one wants, and ask no more"). And, from the 1912 edition of *Il Milione*, [chapter XCIII](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Il_milione_(Laterza,1912)/XCIII)

> Signore re, aguale ben **puoti** vedere che tu non se’ da guerreggiare con meco.

The passage from *puote* to *può* is in line with the elision of many final *-te* and *-de* in Italian: from *cittade* to *città* and from *virtute* to *virtù*.

It is a bit harder to explain how to go from *puoti* to *puoi*. I was unable to find a solid indication of the reason for this change in the literature (Röhlfs simply says it is a "simplification"). The best conjecture I can make is that this is by analogy to the (regular) form *vuoi* of *volere*. This is supported by the existence of an archaic third singular form *puole* or *pole* clearly influenced from *vuole* that survived in various regional languages (cfr. *pòle* in Pisa, *pöl* in Turin, *pòle* in Treia (Marche) and *pól* in Venice).

It is not impossible that this passed through an uncertainly attested **puoli* (by analogy with the archaic *vuoli*), which lost the intervocalic *l* as it happened for many other words.  Of course analogic pressure from *può* cannot be discarded either.